# Error: Could not find or load main class using XML

Tags: java, xml, ant

I am trying to implement my build.xml file so I can compile and create a Jar using ANT.  In order to run some JUnit tests I need to first manually start up a custom Server on port 7777.  However, I am having trouble starting the server up using XML.  This is my code so far:

```
<property name="server" location="cs.hw4.Server"/> 
<target name="run">
    <java fork="true" failonerror="yes" classname="${server}">
        <classpath refid="cs.hw4.classpath"/>
        <arg line="7777"/>
        </java>
</target>
```

I run the build.xml and I get the: Error: `Could not find or load main class F:...`

I am finding that the error is trying to find class in the directory:

> ...\cs.hw4\cs.hw4.Server

When it is actually in:

> ...\cs.hw4\ **bin** \cs.hw4.Server

The funny thing is that the classpath `refid= "cs.hw4.classpath"` includes the "bin" folder.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. Right click on the ant build file and run as you should see a window that pops out with the Classpath and Jar file path. Remove that and add it manually. This time you should see no conflicts.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, so if you mean Run As --> Ant Build... --> Classpath tab then I went there and added the bin folder to the classpath.  However, that didn't work.

Comment: @Keven I did that before and worked for me. I have changed the classpath and rebuild to see whether it is clean. And when i run i found no conflicts.

Comment: FYI-by using "value=" instead of "location=" I fixed the issue.